# Closed pipe/sound resonance sound type sound coming from mineral processing plant

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air, vibrations

I work near a very large mineral processing plant which does vibrate our building and there is also a sound/feeling very similar to the closed pipe/sound resonance that is achieved when opening a back window only of a moving car.

It feels like a constant pressure change at very high frequency.

For health and general annoyance reasons I am looking into this as the workforce is currently getting dismissed by management. For my work I use a high precision vibration monitor in which we can gather some data of the vibration but I have a feeling that would only be measuring half the problem.

Is there a better way to describe this closed pipe/sound resonance situation, is there a way of measuring it and does anyone know of any acceptable limits for humans...etc?